# how to get process / daemon / program state change notification in linux

Tags: linux, process, daemon

I am trying to log each and every process state change . In few operating system i have came across something called process state change notification . when ever a process state is changed we will get the notification . Kernel does maintain each and ever process state right ? .

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you can explore the running processes in the `/proc/` file system. You can read more about it in [The Linux Documentation Project on /proc/](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html).

Comment: yes but what if the process is killed as well , what if multiple state change happened very fast .

Comment: @manimuthuma If you lose your CPU then I'm afraid you won't be able to do anything with the computer.

Comment: @manimuthuma Are you wondering what happens if your monitoring process is killed? You'd probably have to deal with that in all the different ways it's dealt with for any other process - you restart it in some way or another. Reasonably you let systemd manage your process life cycle.

Comment: how will i get to know if some processor is killed or not , won't that be removed from proc folder

Comment: i dont think monitor proc folder is the right solution , it has lot of cons . i am looking for system level solution

Comment: This is a system level solution. You know that a process has been killed because its no longer in /proc/, for example. You can watch /proc/ with inotify just as with any other file.